# decimal to binary 2's complement oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Convert a number to Binary's 2's compliment-

I have a sample number in a column of oracle table - 1647795600

I want to convert this to binary 2's compliment.

Expected output-01100010001101110101110110010000

Reference link - https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html

Comment: [Why](https://xyproblem.info/) are you trying to do this in the DB? [Homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527)?  Same class as [s pragathi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72008795/90527)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dec_to_2c_bin(
  value IN PLS_INTEGER,
  width IN PLS_INTEGER := 32
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_unsigned PLS_INTEGER;
  v_binary   VARCHAR2(201);
BEGIN
  IF value < 0 THEN
    v_unsigned := -1 - value;
  ELSE
    v_unsigned := value;
  END IF;
  WHILE ( v_unsigned > 0 ) LOOP
     v_binary := MOD(v_unsigned, 2) || v_binary;
     v_unsigned := TRUNC( v_unsigned / 2 );
  END LOOP;
  IF LENGTH(v_binary) > width - 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'The value is too large.');
  END IF;
  v_binary := LPAD(v_binary, width, '0');
  IF value < 0 THEN
    RETURN TRANSLATE(v_binary, '01', '10');
  ELSE
    RETURN v_binary;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT +1647795600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -1647795600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       25143 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       +3142 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       -3142 FROM DUAL;
```

The query:

```sql
SELECT value, dec_to_2c_bin(value, 64) AS binary2c
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | BINARY2C |
| --- | --- |
| 1647795600 | 0000000000000000000000000000000001100010001101110101110110010000 |
| -1647795600 | 1111111111111111111111111111111110011101110010001010001001110000 |
| 25143 | 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110001000110111 |
| 3142 | 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110001000110 |
| -3142 | 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001110111010 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=38654b6679c6252c6aa0ad47158cb644)*

Answer (score 0):

I found a statement which worked fine for sample number tested-
select reverse(max(replace(sys_connect_by_path(mod(trunc(&N/power(2,level-1)),2),' '),' ',''))) bin
from dual
connect by level <= 32
;

But might not completely useful, need to modify to read from table.