# Convert Binary's 2's compliment to decimal in oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a sample number in a column of oracle table which is binary's 2's complimanet -
e.g **`0110001000110111`**

I want to convert this to normal decimal number in 2's compliment.

Expected output-

Reference link - https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html

Comment: [Why](https://xyproblem.info/) are you trying to do this in the DB? [Homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527)?  Same class as [Dwaipayan Biswas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72008362/90527)?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop as applying powers of **2** while multiplying by each bit(**0** or **1**) starting from the right end of your presented value such as

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  bin_nr VARCHAR2(100) := '0110001000110';
  dec_nr NUMBER;
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(bin_nr)
  LOOP 
   dec_nr := NVL(dec_nr,0) + SUBSTR(bin_nr,-i,1)*(2**(i-1));   
  END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dec_nr);
END; 
/
```

which results **3142** as the decimal value.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c3b60a662ee0dc9b8cee750f693e214e)</kbd>

Comment: This gets the wrong answer for negative numbers as it does not apply 2's compliment.

Answer (score 0):

For 2s compliment, the most-significant bit represents the sign bit and if that is `1` then you have a negative number:

```sql
DECLARE
  bin_nr  VARCHAR2(100) := '1111001110111010';
  sign    PLS_INTEGER;
  dec_nr  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF SUBSTR(bin_nr, 1, 1) = '1' THEN
    bin_nr := TRANSLATE(bin_nr, '01', '10');
    sign   := -1;
    dec_nr := 1;
  ELSE
    sign   := 1;
    dec_nr := 0;
  END IF;
  FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH(bin_nr) LOOP
    IF SUBSTR(bin_nr, -i, 1) = '1' THEN
      dec_nr := dec_nr + POWER(2, i-1);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  dec_nr := dec_nr * sign;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dec_nr);
END;   
/
```

Outputs `-3142`

If you are expecting an N-bit binary number as the input (for example, the link in the question expects a 16-bit binary number as an input for 2s compliment) then you should `LPAD` with zeroes if you have fewer than that many bits.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1e7a52781d74d9f5efe1e47318de96d8)*